# Laravel cast array still returns a string

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

When retrieving a column I'd like to get it as an array, however it's returned as a string.

**Migration**

```
$table->text('balance')->nullable();
```

**On the model (as per the Laravel docs)**

```
protected $casts = [
   'balance' => 'array',
];
```

**When saving data to the balance column**

```
$exchange = Exchange::findOrFail($id);
$exchange->balance = json_encode($balance);
$exchange->save();
```

**When retrieving the model**

```
$exchanges = Exchange::orderBy('title')->get();
```

**In the view**

```
foreach($exchanges as $ex)
   echo gettype($ex->balance) // This returns string, not an array
endforeach
```

I'm puzzled as to why it's still a string while it should be an array. I've also tried the `json` instead of `text` column type in the migration, same result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you config your model to cast an attribute to `array`, you don't need to convert it back to `json` when trying to store it, Laravel will handle this for you. From the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting):

> #### [Array & JSON Casting](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting)
>
> ...
>
> Once the cast is defined, you may access the `options` attribute and
>   it will automatically be deserialized from JSON into a PHP array. When
>   you set the value of the `options` attribute, the given array **will**
>   **automatically be serialized back into JSON** for storage:
>
> ```
> $user = App\User::find(1);
>
> $options = $user->options;
>
> $options['key'] = 'value';
>
> $user->options = $options;
>
> $user->save();
> ```

So in your case:

```
$exchange = Exchange::findOrFail($id);
$exchange->balance = ['your', 'values', 'as', 'an', 'array'];
$exchange->save();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the cast and implement an [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators) method on the `Exchange` model:

```
public function getBalanceAttribute($value)
{
    return json_decode($value);
}
```

And consume normally like you want:

```
foreach($exchanges as $ex)
   echo gettype($ex->balance)
endforeach
```

Comment: If I use the accessor method it returns an Object, not an array?

Comment: I like this approach. I feel it gives you better flexibility with the data. You can even add the `setBalanceAttribute` method to `json_encode` your value.

Comment: @eskimo Try using `json_decode($value, true)` to return an array instead of an object.